# How can I use Go to make a GUI window?

Tags: go, window

I am in need to make a simple window in Go to display some text,
there is no need for a real GUI like interface.

How can I make a window like this using Go?

Comment: To create a window where? In terminal? What kind of window?

Comment: Go's standard library has no support for GUI windows. For 3rd party packages supporting text-based (terminal) UI, check out [Awesome Go: Advanced Console UIs](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#advanced-console-uis); for graphical UI check out [Awesome Go: GUI](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#gui).

Comment: Found that one too: https://github.com/alexflint/gallium

Comment: You also can use [gxui](https://github.com/google/gxui).

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Not really a good suggestion: _"Unfortunately due to a shortage of hours in a day, GXUI is no longer maintained."_ Last commit was Oct 2015.

Comment: @icza, yes, but I actually don't know the best choice for simple GUI at Go. Walk only for Windows ,  wxGo is very heavyweight as and go-qt. Maybe go-libui - the screenshots look nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

walk is the most common library used for basic GUI development.

You can import the package using:

**go get github.com/lxn/walk**

I assume you are working at windows OS so create an exe and run it.

More Information about this can be gathered from its source.

Visit https://github.com/lxn/walk

Answer (score 4):

A nice-looking cross-platform UI can be created using HTML5/CSS/JS. You may open a native window with a full-screen browser engine (webview) in it showing your UI.

There is a tiny wrapper library for webviews on Windows, MacOS and Linux - https://github.com/zserge/webview

You can connectyour UI and the core app parts using Go-to-JS bindings (webview library provides those) or a websocket.

Comment: If  he's only targeting e.g. Windows, why would you recommend web view? Would be a large amount of bloat when native alternatives exist.
Especially since he's only displaying some text, loading an entire web view seems a bit overkill.